# Set priority for an SQL Server role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to set priority for a role if a user falls in two roles?

EXAMPLE : If the user is a member of the manager and staff roles, I want to get the features of the manager on conflicting issues.

Delete is denied in staff while granted in manager and user1 is a member of both, then user1 could delete the data.

Comment: Is delete for staff `DENY`ed, or merely not `GRANT`ed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever DENY ed..

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever all the employees are staff, but manager is manager and of course he is staff

Comment: Usually, `DENY` should only be used when you're dealing with nested roles, the "outer" role has been `GRANT`ed some permission, and you wish to prevent someone with the "inner" role from using that permission. It sounds like staff is the "outer"-most role - they shouldn't have any `DENY`s.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately for you, it does not work that way. Users in multiple roles are subject to the complete set of permissions from all of their roles, and deny permissions always trump grant permissions. You have to keep that in mind as you design your user and role assignments.

In this case, you might find that you don't need the DENY rule at all. A user can't do anything without explicit grant permissions, so if you remove the deny rule from your staff role they likely still won't be able to delete anything: the rule is redundant for them.

Answer (score 3):

When a user is a member of multiple roles, their allowed permissions are the union of the individual role's `GRANT`s and `DENY`s - with `DENY`s always taking precedence over `GRANT`s.

So, in your case, if it's merely that staff are not `GRANT`ed permission to delete, and managers *are* `GRANT`ed delete, then a member of both roles will be allowed to delete.

There are no ways to change this policy - its built into SQL Server.